# Does EGL require a GPU?

Tags: opengl, virtual-machine, gpu, egl

I am trying to do server-side rendering for a problem that I am working on. EGL provides a way to define a context for OpenGL without the need for a windowing system. I have been able to successfully render offscreen using EGL on my laptop, but when I try to run to the code on an instance on digitalocean EGL fails to initialize. The ability to run this code on a compute resource from a cloud provider is one of the use-cases I need to support.

I want to know if EGL is a viable approach but I don't understand why it is failing. Does it require a GPU? Is this a problem with running on a virtual machine?

The following code reproduces the problem I am experiencing,

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {                                                  

    EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    assert(display != EGL_NO_DISPLAY);

    EGLBoolean result = eglInitialize(display, NULL, NULL); 
    //assert(result != EGL_FALSE);              

    EGLint errcode = eglGetError();
    assert(errcode == EGL_SUCCESS);                             

    return 0;                                                                      
}
```

The error code returned after calling eglInitialize is EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED and, from the header, this means "EGL is not initialized, or could not be initialized, for the specified EGL display connection." The default display is returned without error, so I assume that the problem is that it could not be initialized. So I am trying to work out why is was not initialized.

Comment: I am in the same situation. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use EGL with hardware acceleration, you need a GPU. So a server without GPU provides little benefit.

If you want to still render on the server in software and use the OpenGL API you can look into the [mesaGL](https://www.mesa3d.org) software implementation.

But if you are rendering in software, you can start using any other approaches, such as a a software ray tracer, such as [pov ray](http://www.povray.org/)

Comment: My goal was to not have to modify the rendering code, but to use EGL to define whether the output from the rendering would be on screen or to a texture because I want to support both use cases.